# Is there a way to draw a rectangle into a PdfPCell in iText (the Java version)?

Tags: java, itext

I found some tutorials about how to draw forms in iText, but I need to insert it into a cell, and I don´t know how.
Thank you for your consideration of this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iText Image extends Rectangle. You could make a new implementation of image.

You can create an Image from a template, and you can create a template using a content byte.

You could therefore create a template, draw a rectangle on it, create the image and then set the image on the desired cell. I have done something similar with a rectangle pattern some time back.

Edit: If you just need to fill the entire cell you can use the `setBackground` and `setBorder` methods.

Comment: many thanks Jes. But could you please give an example of how to do make a rectangle or square shape and insert it into a PdfPCell then?. I´m making a form using tables and inside there is a sex field that must be filled by the client. Please help Jes. Thanks again.

Comment: Firstly you need to create a template with the ´cb.createTemplate()´ method. Now you can draw anything you want on that template (since templates are content bytes). Once you have drawn whatever you needed, you can create an itext image from it. See http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/Drawrectangle.htm for how to draw an rectangle.

Answer (score 8):

Since google is not giving any good responses for a complete code example of this and I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to do this (even if Jes explanation now seems pretty clear...) I figured I'll post an example so further seekers can have a complete code example.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
table.setTotalWidth(450);

PdfTemplate template = cb.createTemplate(30, 30);
template .setLineWidth(0.5f);
template .rectangle(0, 0, 17f, 17f);
template .stroke();

Image img = Image.getInstance(template);        
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(img, 1f, 1f);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(chunk);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: This gives me an effect however where the rectangle appears with a bezel effect on the stroke. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

`PdfPCell` has a method to set an image [`PdfPCell#setImage(Image)`](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfPCell.html#setImage%28com.itextpdf.text.Image%29). Couldn't you use it?

Comment: mmm I´ll try it. But what I´d really want is to insert a rectangle shape into a cell, not an image. Thanks Boris.