# How to place cells vertically in a table in itextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I want to place cells vertically in table. Normally, it is placed as follows: [image: https://imgur.com/a/EPTqobR]

But I want to this: [image: https://imgur.com/a/hrDz2aZ]

That way, I'm gonna put 10 contents in the cells. Waiting for your helps.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
table.AddCell("content 1");
table.AddCell("content 2");
table.AddCell("content 3");
table.AddCell("content 4");
document.Add(table);
```

Comment: See [Horizontal text alignment in a PdfPCell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18199344/719186)

Comment: Itext only offers to add table cells row-wise. If your data is arranged column-wise, you need to re-arrange it. If not otherwise possible, add your data to a 2-dimensional array at the correct position and thereafter add the data from that array row-by-row to the table.

Comment: Thanks @mkl I will add my data to a 2 dmiensional array.