# Need to make PDF sample with boxes as table columns by android app

Tags: java, android, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I need to make PDF sample file just like the below image but I didn't find any suitable guide to do exactly like this. I have followed some links

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=102

[Is there a way to draw a rectangle into a PdfPCell in iText (the Java version)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429038/is-there-a-way-to-draw-a-rectangle-into-a-pdfpcell-in-itext-the-java-version)

but from the second link I didn't understand how could I make more likely to my requirement.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Do you have the option of manually creating a template PDF, and then populating the data for each copy of the PDF? That's going to be easier to create/maintain in the long run, rather than drawing it on the fly each time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, for the top box with four attributes, I have that option to make a template but the 2nd box, there needs to add rows dynamically (there could be 2 ,3 or many name and signature rows). One more is that the signature field will take a image of signature.

Comment: I guess a library like JasperReports should make this a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear to me why you refer to this example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=102
The PDF that is created with that example shows me in a Superman outfit. What is the link with creating a table with rounded borders?

Please take a look at the [NestedTableRoundedBorder](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/NestedTableRoundedBorder) example. It creates a PDF that looks like this: [nested_table_rounded_border.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/nested_table_rounded_border.pdf)

[image]

This construction consists of nested tables. The outer table only has one column, but we use it to create the rounded corners:

```
class RoundRectangle implements PdfPCellEvent {
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect,
            PdfContentByte[] canvas) {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        cb.roundRectangle(
            rect.getLeft() + 1.5f, rect.getBottom() + 1.5f, rect.getWidth() - 3,
            rect.getHeight() - 3, 4);
        cb.stroke();
    }
}
```

This cell event is used like this:

```
cell = new PdfPCell(innertable);
cell.setCellEvent(roundRectangle);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setPadding(8);
outertable.addCell(cell);
```

The inner tables are used to create cells with or without borders, for instance like this:

```
// inner table 1
PdfPTable innertable = new PdfPTable(5);
innertable.setWidths(new int[]{8, 12, 1, 4, 12});
// first row
// column 1
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Record Ref:"));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innertable.addCell(cell);
// column 2
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("GN Staff"));
cell.setPaddingLeft(2);
innertable.addCell(cell);
// column 3
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innertable.addCell(cell);
// column 4
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date: "));
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innertable.addCell(cell);
// column 5
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("30/4/2015"));
cell.setPaddingLeft(2);
innertable.addCell(cell);
// spacing
cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setColspan(5);
cell.setFixedHeight(3);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
innertable.addCell(cell);
```

If some of the dimensions are quite like you want, it's sufficient to change parameters such as the widths array, the padding, the fixed height, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response, I think my problem has been solved.

Comment: AGPL license on iText!

Comment: Yes @vihkat, that's the license if you want to use iText gor free. If you can't adhere to the AGPL license, a commercial license will be needed.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have a table whose content is in more than one page. The rounded rectangle border is not generating for this table. But, it displays for the table that can fit in a single page. Is there any solution?